# How to get rid of weird box characters in PDFs generated with Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I am running a Rails 6 app where users can convert their contents into PDFs.

I am using [Prawn](https://prawnpdf.org) to generate the PDFs.

Most PDFs look fine but some of them contain empty (?) box characters. I simply don't understand where they come from and I have no way of asking our users. This is a screenshot of one of those PDF files:

[image]

How can I get rid of those box characters?

My guess is that our users are copying contents from their word processors (e.g. MS Word) and that these contents contain hidden formatting, tabs, etc.

How can I get rid of those?

Comment: The boxes are most probably characters which don't have glyphs in the font you use. Have a look at the strings (and their individual Unicode characters) that produce the wrong output and compare them with the visual representation. Maybe tab characters?

Comment: Yes, @gettalong, that's what I thought but where would I find those Unicode characters? I can't find them in the database. All I see in the database is little bits of whitespace where there shouldn't be any.

Comment: You need to read those strings into Ruby and then do something like `str.codepoints`. Then you will get the Unicode codepoints for the string and can find out what the whitespace you see really is.

Comment: When I access the records from `rails console` I can see the tab characters: `24.09.2020\tFK\tInterview 4` (These where indeed invisible in my database browser.) I guess now it's just a matter of replacing `\t` upon user entry. Just wonder what's the best way to do that...

Comment: You could probably do this on validation of the strings before pushing the data to the database. What you replace the tabs with is up to you: Could be one space or four spaces or something else. Documenting it for you users so that they aren't surprised does the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, fixing this issue was pretty simple. I just hadn't realise that *tabs* were causing the trouble and that Prawn has no way of handling them (apparently).

So to make Prawn happy I just did this in my model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord

   before_save :replace_tabs

   def replace_tabs
     number_of_spaces = 4
     description.gsub!("\t", ' ' * number_of_spaces)
   end

end
```